# How to show a PDF page by page using horizontal swipe in iphone?

Tags: iphone, pdf, uitouch, horizontal-scrolling, cgpdfdocument

I want to create a page by page PDF reader.

I know how UIWebView can be used to show the PDF but It will load the entire PDF and want to show one page at a time.

The PDF is stored locally.
Next and previous PDF Pages should be loaded depending on the horizontal swipe.

How to show a single page along with horizontal Swipe and  Zooming functionalities ?
What is the best approach for such problem?
Is there any tutorial for this?

EDIT :
I have used CGPDF APIs to show the PDF page by page.
I am using the PDF page as image.
But zooming is not working properly as UIPageControl is also used.
How to zoom these images along with page control ?

Answer (score 10):

You can use Leaves View, you can find tutorial from

https://github.com/brow/leaves

second option is FastPDFKit, you can get it from

http://mobfarm.eu/

According to me leaves is more preferable because memory management is good and it is more user friendly.

**EDIT:**

You can consider two more options which provide some good features for PDF.

1. [Reader on Github](https://github.com/vfr/Reader)
2. [PSPDFKit](http://pspdfkit.com/)

**Note**: PSPDFKit is not free.

**EDIT:**
Since iOS 5, you can add an effect of swiping the page like iBooks. To do it that way you can use [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html). To get some basic idea, just create an app with ***page-based application*** from your Xcode template or you can refer to [this link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application).

Answer (score 0):

you add as a subLayer the tiledLayer that draws the PDF page (CGContextDrawPDFPage) to a UIView and then you add that as a subview to a UIScrolView. That way you have a PDF page that you can zoom by pinching it and  you can scroll.

Lets say you create a class PDFViewController:

[myContentView.layer addSublayer:tiledLayer];
...
[scrollView addSubview:myContentView];
...
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

and then you should create MagazineViewController class where you have a large horizontal UIScrollView where you create the views from the PDFViewController that contain the pages, That way you have a view that you can swipe horizontally and see the pages of a magazine or a book.